# Update mouse position Gradually

Tags: jquery

I have method implementing the code below ,

```
var previuosX=objectPositionX;
if (!e) var e = window.event;
if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
     currentPositionX = e.pageX;
     cuurentPositionY = e.pageY;
}
```

so i retrieve the mouse position like this , and by using this i will update the position of an object as ,

```
var deltaX=previuosX-currentPositionX;
objectPositionX= objectPositionX-deltaX;
previuosX=currentPositionX;
```

saying that i always move the object to left (horizontally always) side so the 'previuosX' always remains positive , and i used to preserve the value of 'previuosX' everytime .

The problem is whenever i move my mouse faster , 'currentPositionX' value will be higher so the difference 'deltaX' is higher , thus now the object is moved to a newer farther distance , but it jumps to new position instead of moving gradually , i need to move the object gradually with bigger differnces , any idea ?.

Answer (score 0):

Sample the movement. Only take every 10th/50th/100th/whatever is appropriate offset change then. It'll still capture the pace of the mouse movements but slow down your on screen movement.